# Can i add a comma (,) dynamically to a CSS pseudo element which its value is coming from CSS variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to insert the commas appropriately between the numbers.
eg: 6,350

is there any way I can achieve this in the following scenario

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  $('.number-counter').each(function () {
    $(this).addClass('inView');
  });
}, 500);
```

```css
@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.number-counter {
  transition: --num 3s;
  counter-set: num var(--num);
  font: 800 40px system-ui;
}
.number-counter::after {
  content: counter(num);
}
.number-counter.inView {
  --num: var(--count);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="number-counter" style="--count: 6350;"></div>
```

Comment: Just assign `content: counter(num) ",";` then. (And overwrite that again with the version without the comma for the last number, if you don't want a comma behind that as well.)

Comment: thanks for the response cBroe. but I want the coma between numbers. for eg: 6,350, 2,66,350 etc

Comment: I don't think that will be possible in CSS alone, you'll probably have to switch to the JS part already properly formatting the number in a string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to add this code in CSS but there is no way to count the digits in CSS so I have added the comma(,) using jQuery. I hope this will help you. It will add the comma after 3 digit.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  jQuery('.number-counter').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('inView');
    var $this = jQuery(this);
     countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
  jQuery({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({countNum: countTo},
    {     
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
              $this.text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.ceil(this.countNum)));
  },
  complete: function() {
    $this.text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.ceil(this.countNum)));
      }
    });
  });
}, 500);
function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
  while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
    val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  return val;
}
```

```css
@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.number-counter {
  transition: --num 3s;
  counter-set: num var(--num);
  font: 800 40px system-ui;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number-counter" style="--count: 6350;" data-count="6350"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for the response, and this alternative solution. its working well